# What am I? - Another object riddle

Tags: riddle

> I am made of something,
>
> But also made of nothing.
>
> My contents are true,
>
> Yet also false.
>
> I speak to many things,
>
> Yet never say a word.
>
> Almost everyone uses me,
>
> Yet few know me.
>
> What am I?

*Explain every line of the riddle in your answer in order for it to be counted correct.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are

> a computer program

I am made of something,

> Programming is definitely something...

But also made of nothing.

> ...but programs have no physical presensce.

My contents are true,

> In binary, a program is made up of ones (true)...

Yet also false.

> ... and zeros (false).

I speak to many things,

> Computer programs control/issue instructions to/speak to many devices...

Yet never say a word.

> ...but they don't use words.

Almost everyone uses me,

> I'm using a computer program right now...

Yet few know me.

> ...but I haven't the foggiest idea how to write a program.